# NVL function with CLOB datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have this query:

`select LENGTH(NVL(exam.vl_result,' ')) from exam;`

And I got this error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

The column `vl_result` is CLOB, but I need to use NVL in this case. Is there any way to use NVL with datatype CLOB? If not, what can be the best way to get a similar query.

Comment: I am using oracle 11g and able to use NVL with clob column. Infact i treid the same query as you and it worked for me. Which oracle version you are using ?

Comment: Unfourtunately I'm using Oracle 10g :(

Comment: then try the below give solutions, if they work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case..when` as follows:

```
select case when exam.vl_result is null then 1 
            else LENGTH(exam.vl_result) 
       end 
  from exam;
```

**Note:** To find the length of clob use `dbms_lob.getlength`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . how about running `length()` first:

```
coalesce(length(exam.vl_result), 1)
```

Comment: It works, but there is another functions that I have just NVL(clob, ' ') for example. But thanks!